# Save php generated excel in react

Tags: laravel, reactjs, phpexcel

I'm using laravel excel package to generate xls file. When I'm sending get request I can see excel file in my response(random characters), however there is no prompt to save it(I guess react blocking it on front end).   What would be the right way to implement it?

React onclick listener:

```
function handleClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get('excel', function(data) {
    //alert(data);
  });
}
```

Laravel controller:

```
public function generateExcel()
{
    return Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) {
        $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) {
            // Sheet manipulation
        });
     })->download('xls');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, react is blocking your download.  The download prompt happens because of the HTTP headers. So, guessing you have a laravel url for you xls like `/laravel/get/xls` you should have.

```
<a href="/laravel/get/xls" target="_blank">Get Xls</a>
```

In this way you'll open a new tab in which the http headers will prompt for the download.